# How to know current element transform translate3d value in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag

```
<div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-1636px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0.9s; width: 2570px; margin-left: 0px;">
....
</div>
```

and hover class for this

```
.owl-stage:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1280px, 0, 0) !important;
    transform: translate3d(-1280px, 0, 0) !important;
    transition: 450ms transform, 450ms -webkit-transform;
}
```

owl stage transform translate3d value is changed automatically (-1636px to -1108px or something) when button is click.

I want to subtract -200px in .owl-stage:hover from its current value.
(eg -1636 - 200px so value is -1836px and hover code will become like that

```
.owl-stage:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1836px, 0, 0) !important;
    transform: translate3d(-1836px, 0, 0) !important;
    transition: 450ms transform, 450ms -webkit-transform;
}
```

The problem is every time user clicks on button, .owl-stage translate3d value is changed. So I can't hardcode in CSS file.
I want to set value for translate3d automatically in .owl-stage:hover class according to conditions without using Javascript or jQuery.
is it possible? if so, how can I do?

Comment: the 3rd code box you've posted is wrong, transform and -webkit-transform are the same and should have the same value on the same class.  To subtract a value from the current value you need js.

Comment: i corrected. is there any way to do only in CSS? @vlk

Comment: Can't you apply your relative transforms on the content of your div, which would act as a wrapper : https://jsfiddle.net/xace9wrr/1

Comment: @taymyinl no you need js